# Mobile website crawling

Tags: java, android, mobile, web-crawler

Am using the following code to crawl the websites(which i pass from another function) and get the details that I want. It works perfectly when i use on a desktop but I have problem while using the same code in an Android app on a mobile phone.

```
public class urlfinder{
    public String web =null;
    public urlfinder(String website)
    {
        this.web = website;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(web);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            /* I get the required details here */
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: when i execute the code on a desktop/laptop the code works perfectly fine. but when i do the same through an Android app, it doesn't as the code is not able to crawl through a mobile website.
For example in the app if I pass "facebook.com" , I am able to retrieve the details but not with "m.facebook.com"